# Is it a good idea to use enum mysql data format to event log types? I'm going to use maximum 10-12 event types

Tags: mysql, string, enums, format

For example:
- login
- logout
- view
- create
- modify
- export
- import
- unauthorized access
- etc.

Comment: I would create a log_types table and have a foreign key relationship. This way if you need to add/change/delete some, you don't have to worry about updating every row in the log.

Comment: Why should I worry about updating? The enum values could be modified anytime.

Comment: Yeah, try to update the list of values for an enum in a large transaction table...

Comment: Okay, I understand, but when does it make sense to use ENUM? I read that it is much faster when sorting. (I hope log types will rarely change.)